# Need Help Writing Loops

Tags: java, for-loop

New to Java and I need to write a program that prints out the numbers from one to 100 in 10 rows and columns, incrementing first down the column using nested loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried, but it's not printing the right numbers.

```
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 1 ; j <= 10; j++ ) { 
        System.out.printf("%4d", i*j ); 
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: This site has degenerated into do.my.homework.for.me.com.  I hope that anyone who actually answers this learns as much from doing the OP's homework, as OP is going to learn by copy-pasting it into their assignment.

Comment: for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 10; i++ ) {
         for ( int j = 1 ; j <= 10; j++ ) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", i*j );
         }
         System.out.println();
      }

Comment: OK, that's a really good start.  The only problem is that `i*j` isn't what you want to print.  I think it's actually `10*(i-1)+j` that you want instead.  Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int count=1;
    for (int a=1;a<=100;a++)
    {
        if (count<10)
        {
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(a+"\t"));
        count++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(a);
            count=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + count);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Give name App.java to file, run at your cmd line "javac App.java" and then "java App"

Comment: Did you intend to have a funky parallelogram effect?  Or did you just not test this?

Answer (score 0):

using two nested loops this would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=10; j++){
            System.out.print(i*10+j + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```